# Why is my std::map losing its values?

Tags: c++

I have a class polynomial which has a member object polyMap.

```
std::map<int,int> polyMap;

Polynomial() {}
Polynomial(const Polynomial& rhs){
    polyMap=rhs.polyMap;
}
~Polynomial() {

}
```

I'm reading lines from a file and populating the map using pairs of ints, one int as the key and the other as the value.

I use a function to populate multiple polynomials from a text file, and populate their maps

```
Polynomial* populateFields(const char* filename) {
ifstream infile(filename);
int i;
int z;
string s;

Polynomial* arr = new Polynomial[numLinesInFile(filename)];
int index = 0;
while (!infile.eof()) {
    getline(infile, s);
    stringstream t(s);
    Polynomial* poly = new Polynomial;
    arr[index] = *poly;
    index = index + 1;
    while (t >> i >> z) {
        poly->polyMap[z] = i;
      }
    }
   return arr;
 }
```

When i attempt to access the a polynomials map in the main function, its values always return zero.

Why do my maps lose the values? From what I understand maps are smart pointers, is the map objects destructor being called at the end of my populateFields function?

Comment: You are leaking every single one of the polynomials that you `new Polynomial()`. I also don't see any smart pointers anywhere in your question.

Comment: [OT]: `std::vector<Polynomial>` instead of raw pointer.

Comment: @CoryKramer My question is about the std::map, which is a smart pointer. Not about user defined smart pointers. Also, thanks for pointing out the memory leaks. Still didn't answer my question though.

Comment: @BeardedDev A `std::map` is *not* a smart pointer. Smart pointers are generally one of `std::unique_ptr`, `std::shared_ptr`, `std::weak_ptr`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do the copy before initializing the data:

```
while (getline(infile, s)) {
    stringstream t(s);
    Polynomial poly;
    while (t >> i >> z) {
        poly.polyMap[z] = i;
    }
    arr[index] = poly;
    index = index + 1;
}
```

Or rewritten with `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<Polynomial> populateFields(const char* filename) {
    std::vector<Polynomial> res;
    std::ifstream infile(filename);
    std::string s;
    while (getline(infile, s)) {
        std::stringstream t(s);

        res.emplace_back();
        Polynomial& poly = res.back();
        int i;
        int z;
        while (t >> i >> z) {
            poly.polyMap[z] = i;
        }
    }
    return res;
 }
```

Comment: When you declare `Polynomial poly`, doesn't that get allocated on the stack and then deallocated at the end of the block scope (thus making the returned `arr` point to deallocated blocks of memory)? Or is it different in C++ than it is in C?

Comment: You could also just operate directly on `arr[index]`. No need for the intermediate `Polynomial` object and then assignment.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts: We have `Polynomial* arr`, not `Polynomial** arr`, we don't store pointer of the local object, so it is ok.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: I agree, but I would like to point to the right place to do the assignment.

Comment: @Jarod42 oh right, thanks for clarifying that. Each index contains the value rather than the pointer. Got it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do it:

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

struct Polynomial {
    Polynomial(const std::string& line) {
        std::istringstream iss{line};
        for(int i{}, z{}; iss >> i >> z;)
            polyMap[z] = i;
    }
    std::map<int, int> polyMap;
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, std::vector<Polynomial>& poly)
{
    for(std::string line; std::getline(is, line);)
        poly.emplace_back(line);
    return is;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<Polynomial> polys;
    std::ifstream{"infile.txt"} >> polys;
}
```